# Matrix function decomposition of the form $A(\theta)=B(\theta)^\top Q B(\theta)$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, functions, reference-request, matrix-decomposition

Suppose I have a matrix function $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, for which I know the following properties hold:

- $A(\theta)$ is real, symmetric and bounded for all $\theta$
- $A(\theta)$ is a $\mathcal{C}_1$ function, i.e., $A(\theta)$ and $\frac{\partial A(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ are continuous.
- There exist two constants $0<c_1\le c_2$ such that for all $\theta$, $c_1I\preccurlyeq A(\theta)\preccurlyeq c_2 I$. (so it is positive definite for all $\theta$)

Is it true that this matrix can **always** be represented in the following form?
$$A(\theta)=B(\theta)^\top Q B(\theta),$$
where $0\prec Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\det(B(\theta))\neq 0$ for all $\theta$.

My intuition says yes, just take power to a half (so $B(\theta) = A(\theta)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $Q=I$. But, I cannot find any reference that 'exploits' this fact. So, my question is, could you give a reference that shows/claims this, or prove this yourself (:P)?

Edit: I was also thinking about eigenfunction of the matrix function. However, I'm not sure how this connects exactly to the decomposition above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you want $B(\theta)$ to be $C^1$. If so, yes, you can take $B(\theta)=A(\theta)^{1/2}$ and $Q=I$.

Denote the set of all real symmetric matrices by $\mathcal S$ and the set of all positive definite matrices by $\mathcal P$. Then $\mathcal P$ is open in the $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$-dimensional real vector space $\mathcal S$. The positive definite square root function $g(A)= A^{1/2}$ is well-defined on $\mathcal P$. In fact, given $ A$, its positive definite square root uniquely determined by the Lagrange interpolation polynomial that maps each distinct eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ to $\sqrt{\lambda}$.

Now let $ A_0$ be any positive definite matrix and let $B_0=A_0^{1/2}$. Define $f(B)= B^2$ on $S$. Then $f$ is $C^1$ and its Fréchet derivative $Df:X\mapsto BX+XB$ is nonsingular at $B_0$. Therefore, by inverse function theorem, $f$ has a $C^1$ local inverse defined on some neighbourhood $W$ containing $A_0$. Since $\mathcal P$ is open, we may assume that $W\subseteq \mathcal P$. As this local inverse of $f$ gives a positive definite square root function on $W$, it must agree with $g$. Hence $g$ is $C^1$ on $W$. It follows that $g$ is $C^1$ on $\mathcal P$ because $ A_0$ is arbitrary.

Finally, when $A$ is a $C^1$ function of $\theta$, its square root $A(\theta)^{1/2}=g(A(\theta))$ is also $C^1$, by the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm still analyzing it. 2 Q's: 1.  $X$ is here just $\frac{d B}{d \theta}$, right? 2. There is still a minor open thing for me, how is it guaranteed that $B(\theta)^\top B(\theta)=A(\theta)$? With this proof it seems that it is only guaranteed that $B(\theta) B(\theta)=A(\theta)$. Or is $B(\theta)$ guaranteed to be symmetric as $A(\theta)$ is positive definite (hence symmetric)? Can you elaborate a bit on this, please?

Comment: @seaver 1. No. In the first two paragraphs, I am considering $f:B\mapsto B^2$ as a function defined on the $n(n+1)/2$ dimensional Euclidean space $S$. Your $\theta$ enters the discussion only in the last paragraph. $Df$ is the Fréchet derivative of $f$. It is a linear map. $X$ is the argument of $Df$. It is a dummy variable and it bears no relationship to $B$. 2. $B$ is symmetric. Therefore $B^2=A$ means precisely that $B^TB=A$.

Comment: Alright, great, thank you for the explanation. I might have some questions later, as I'm not an expert in this field. But you most certainly deserved the bounty ;-)

Comment: Hi, you really helped me and my coworkers out with this proof, and we want to use it in a paper by means of putting it in a technical note. Is there some way we can include/thank you in the process of putting this out? Please let me know if you are interested and if so how we can reach you :)

Comment: @seaver Thank you. If you feel the need to do so, you may read [this meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4259) about how to do it. In particular, see footnote 7 on p.12 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0325.pdf) for an example. I am glad to remain anonymous.